# C# Повторяющийся атрибут XML

Tags: xml, linq

Есть такой код:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
          new XElement("Cards",
          new XElement("Card",
          new XAttribute("number", labelCard.Text),
          listarticle.Select(i => new XElement("product", new XAttribute("article", i))),
              listcount.Select(a => new XAttribute("counts", a))
              )));
          doc.Save(@"../data/report/" + labelCard.Text + ".xml");
```

Компилятор ругается на второй XElement. Пишет "повторяющийся атрибут. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Ваш вопрос был решен?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так Вы посмотрите что у Вас на выходе получается то..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cards>
  <Card number="..." counts="" counts="..." counts="..." counts="...">
    <product article="..." />
    <product article="..." />
  </Card>
</Cards>
```

> Что делаю не так?

```
listcount.Select(a => new XAttribute("counts", a))
```

Comment: Так если я добавлю за место последней строки, просто new XAttribute("counts", "1"). То он без ошибок выводит XML, где: <product article="..." counts="..." />

Comment: @user1667616, так а Вы обновите свой вопрос и скажите что Вы хотите видеть в файле? XML какой структуры?